# How to run STA/LTA algorithm in Python using spark streaming and kafka?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to run STA/LTA code which is for event detection on spark streaming and using kafka to produce the streaming data but I'm not able to get the result. I have two .py files one containing the STA/LTA code and one containing spark streaming code. My problem is that when I run the sparkkafka.py it doesn't show me any plot of events which should be produced by plot_trigger function. Actually my spark code doesn't do anything. What I'm doing wrong?

```
#STA/LTA.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -------------------------------------------------------------------
# Filename: trigger.py
#  Purpose: Python trigger/picker routines for seismology.
#   Author: Moritz Beyreuther, Tobias Megies
#    Email: moritz.beyreuther@geophysik.uni-muenchen.de
#
# Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Moritz Beyreuther, Tobias Megies
# -------------------------------------------------------------------

from __future__ import (absolute_import, division, print_function,
                        unicode_literals)
from future.builtins import *  # NOQA

from collections import deque
import ctypes as C
import warnings

import numpy as np

from obspy import UTCDateTime
from obspy.signal.cross_correlation import templates_max_similarity
from obspy.signal.headers import clibsignal, head_stalta_t
from numpy import genfromtxt
from obspy import read




def classic_sta_lta(a, nsta, nlta):
    """
    Computes the standard STA/LTA from a given input array a. The length of
    the STA is given by nsta in samples, respectively is the length of the
    LTA given by nlta in samples.

    Fast version written in C.

    :type a: NumPy :class:`~numpy.ndarray`
    :param a: Seismic Trace
    :type nsta: int
    :param nsta: Length of short time average window in samples
    :type nlta: int
    :param nlta: Length of long time average window in samples
    :rtype: NumPy :class:`~numpy.ndarray`
    :return: Characteristic function of classic STA/LTA
    """
    data = a
    # initialize C struct / NumPy structured array
    head = np.empty(1, dtype=head_stalta_t)
    head[:] = (len(data), nsta, nlta)
    # ensure correct type and contiguous of data
    data = np.ascontiguousarray(data, dtype=np.float64)
    # all memory should be allocated by python
    charfct = np.empty(len(data), dtype=np.float64)
    # run and check the error-code
    errcode = clibsignal.stalta(head, data, charfct)
    if errcode != 0:
        raise Exception('ERROR %d stalta: len(data) < nlta' % errcode)
    return charfct
























def trigger_onset(charfct, thres1, thres2, max_len=9e99, max_len_delete=False):
    """
    Calculate trigger on and off times.

    Given thres1 and thres2 calculate trigger on and off times from
    characteristic function.

    This method is written in pure Python and gets slow as soon as there
    are more then 1e6 triggerings ("on" AND "off") in charfct --- normally
    this does not happen.

    :type charfct: NumPy :class:`~numpy.ndarray`
    :param charfct: Characteristic function of e.g. STA/LTA trigger
    :type thres1: float
    :param thres1: Value above which trigger (of characteristic function)
                   is activated (higher threshold)
    :type thres2: float
    :param thres2: Value below which trigger (of characteristic function)
        is deactivated (lower threshold)
    :type max_len: int
    :param max_len: Maximum length of triggered event in samples. A new
                    event will be triggered as soon as the signal reaches
                    again above thres1.
    :type max_len_delete: bool
    :param max_len_delete: Do not write events longer than max_len into
                           report file.
    :rtype: List
    :return: Nested List of trigger on and of times in samples
    """
    # 1) find indices of samples greater than threshold
    # 2) calculate trigger "of" times by the gap in trigger indices
    #    above the threshold i.e. the difference of two following indices
    #    in ind is greater than 1
    # 3) in principle the same as for "of" just add one to the index to get
    #    start times, this operation is not supported on the compact
    #    syntax
    # 4) as long as there is a on time greater than the actual of time find
    #    trigger on states which are greater than last of state an the
    #    corresponding of state which is greater than current on state
    # 5) if the signal stays above thres2 longer than max_len an event
    #    is triggered and following a new event can be triggered as soon as
    #    the signal is above thres1
    ind1 = np.where(charfct > thres1)[0]
    if len(ind1) == 0:
        return []
    ind2 = np.where(charfct > thres2)[0]
    #
    on = deque([ind1[0]])
    of = deque([-1])
    # determine the indices where charfct falls below off-threshold
    ind2_ = np.empty_like(ind2, dtype=bool)
    ind2_[:-1] = np.diff(ind2) > 1
    # last occurence is missed by the diff, add it manually
    ind2_[-1] = True
    of.extend(ind2[ind2_].tolist())
    on.extend(ind1[np.where(np.diff(ind1) > 1)[0] + 1].tolist())
    # include last pick if trigger is on or drop it
    if max_len_delete:
        # drop it
        of.extend([1e99])
        on.extend([on[-1]])
    else:
        # include it
        of.extend([ind2[-1]])
    #
    pick = []
    while on[-1] > of[0]:
        while on[0] <= of[0]:
            on.popleft()
        while of[0] < on[0]:
            of.popleft()
        if of[0] - on[0] > max_len:
            if max_len_delete:
                on.popleft()
                continue
            of.appendleft(on[0] + max_len)
        pick.append([on[0], of[0]])
    return np.array(pick, dtype=np.int64)










def plot_trigger(trace, cft, thr_on, thr_off, show=True):
    """
    Plot characteristic function of trigger along with waveform data and
    trigger On/Off from given thresholds.

    :type trace: :class:`~obspy.core.trace.Trace`
    :param trace: waveform data
    :type cft: :class:`numpy.ndarray`
    :param cft: characteristic function as returned by a trigger in
        :mod:`obspy.signal.trigger`
    :type thr_on: float
    :param thr_on: threshold for switching trigger on
    :type thr_off: float
    :param thr_off: threshold for switching trigger off
    :type show: bool
    :param show: Do not call `plt.show()` at end of routine. That way,
        further modifications can be done to the figure before showing it.
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    df = trace.stats.sampling_rate
    npts = trace.stats.npts
    t = np.arange(npts, dtype=np.float32) / df
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    ax1.plot(t, trace.data, 'k')
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, sharex=ax1)
    ax2.plot(t, cft, 'k')
    on_off = np.array(trigger_onset(cft, thr_on, thr_off))
    i, j = ax1.get_ylim()
    try:
        ax1.vlines(on_off[:, 0] / df, i, j, color='r', lw=2,
                   label="Trigger On")
        ax1.vlines(on_off[:, 1] / df, i, j, color='b', lw=2,
                   label="Trigger Off")
        ax1.legend()
    except IndexError:
        pass
    ax2.axhline(thr_on, color='red', lw=1, ls='--')
    ax2.axhline(thr_off, color='blue', lw=1, ls='--')
    ax2.set_xlabel("Time after %s [s]" % trace.stats.starttime.isoformat())
    fig.suptitle(trace.id)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    if show:
        plt.show()





def main():
    #a = genfromtxt('syntheticData.csv', delimiter=',')
    st = read('http://examples.obspy.org/RJOB_061005_072159.ehz.new')
    trace = st[0]
    #length = len(trace.data)
    #trace.data = a[:length]
    charfct = classic_sta_lta(trace.data, 2, 30)
    trigger_onset(charfct, 4, 2, max_len=9e99, max_len_delete=False)
    plot_trigger(trace, charfct, 4, 2, show=True)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod(exclude_empty=True)
#sparkkafka.py

import sys

#    Spark
from pyspark import SparkContext
#    Spark Streaming
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
#    Kafka
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
import STALTA





# Create a local StreamingContext with two working thread and batch interval of 1 second
sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "STALTA")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
# Connect to Kafka
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, 'localhost:2181', 'spark-streaming-consumer', {'consumer6':1})
kafkaStream.pprint()
# Process the stream
sta_lta_ratio = kafkaStream.map(lambda i: classic_sta_lta(i, 2, 30))
triggers = sta_lta_ratio.flatMap(lambda j: trigger_onset(j, 4, 2, max_len=9e99, max_len_delete=False))
#output stream
kafkaStream.map(lambda k: plot_trigger(k, sta_lta_ratio, 4, 2, show=True))
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

To run the `sparkkafka.py`, put it into the following directory and then run the following command.
Directory: `spark-2.3.1-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/streaming`

Command: `bin/spark-submit --jars jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.3.1.jar examples/src/main/python/streaming/sparkkafka.py localhost:2181 consumer6`

OR

This command: `bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11 examples/src/main/python/streaming/sparkkafka.py localhost:2181 consumer6`

The kafka topic name here in my example is consumer6.

The input file that should be loaded into the kafka is available through the following link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf2cpdlrbwnip14/inputFile.txt?dl=0

After downloading it, put it into the following directory of kafka:

opt/kafka/bin/inputFile.txt

Usefule commands to run the kafka:

1. `sudo /opt/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties`
2. `sudo /opt/kafka/bin/kafka-server-start.sh /opt/kafka/config/server.properties`
3. `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic consumer6`
4. `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test < /opt/kafka/bin/inputFile.txt`
5. `/opt/kafka/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic consumer6 --from-beginning`

Thank you,
Zeinab

Comment: So, what is the question you want to ask?

Comment: @Shaido: My problem is that when I run the sparkkafka.py it doesn't show me  any plot of events which should be produced by plot_trigger function. Actually my spark code doesn't do anything. What I'm doing wrong?